# Query database settings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

Is there an ADO.NET way-to-go to query SQL Server database settings (things like `AllowSnapshotIsolation` or `Is Read Committed Snapshot On`)?

For now we use low-level SQL queries, but maybe there is a supported API for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to explicitly target these properties using the [`sys.databases`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) table within a query as seen below :

```
SELECT name,
       snapshot_isolation_state, 
       is_read_committed_snapshot_on
  FROM sys.databases 
 WHERE name = @YourDatabaseName
```

[The documentation for sys.databases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) should provide all of the various fields that are exposed on the database to give you a better idea of how you might find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is the way we are doing it already. I thought there might be some ADO.NET API to query those. If nobody answers something different in the next 48 hours, I'm going to accept your answer.